# Custom Value in INSERT SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

So As per my needs I have to copy the data from table1 to table2 and for that I'm using the INSERT SELECT QUERY. Here it is :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attribute_details_versions`(`attribute_details_id`,`attribute_name`,`attribute_text`,`attribute_value`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) SELECT `attribute_details_id`,`attribute_name`,`attribute_text`,`attribute_value`,`created_at`,`updated_at`FROM `attribute_details`";
```

In above query the data from `attribute_details` is copying to `attribute_details_versions` table and which is working fine.

**But There is 1 more column `version` in table `attribute_details_versions`** and i need to submit the custom value like any integer value (1 or 2 or etc.) in this column. **this `version column is not exist in`attribute_details` table** so how can i insert this custom value using SELECT INSERT QUERY ?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it the same value for all rows?

Comment: @VMai yes it will be same for all rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it needs to be the same for all values, you can simply select the number it needs to be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attribute_details_versions`(`attribute_details_id`,`attribute_name`,`attribute_text`,`attribute_value`,`created_at`,`updated_at`, `version `) SELECT `attribute_details_id`,`attribute_name`,`attribute_text`,`attribute_value`,`created_at`,`updated_at`, 2 FROM `attribute_details`";
```

Comment: Great...!! I was doing the same thing except 2 as `'2'` and should be only `2`. Now it works.